# DPInst. Specify .sys file location

Tags: windows, windows-xp, drivers, dpinst

I am using **DPInst**-tool to install a driver (I have **.inf** and **.sys** files).
In **dpinst.xml** I specified **search**-element as follows:

```
<search>
    <subDirectory>*</subDirectory>
</search>
```

But during the installation the "**Files needed**" popup-window appears asking me to specify the location of the **.sys** file.
   Is it possible to specify it's location prior the installation in the **dpinst.xml** or maybe in the **.inf**-file?

Answer (score 0):

DPInst searches for the .inf file. You are telling DPInst to search recursivly in all subfolders relative to DPInst working directory. Your .inf file should point to a .sys file.

Look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549520.aspx) for info on .inf files and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff544842.aspx) for more info on DPInst.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be that you keep the driver files (.inf and .sys files) in the same folder where you have kept the dpinst.exe. Then run the exe which will take the current location itself to look for driver files. 
second, dpinst.exe has a "/Path" flag followed by path of the driver files which you want to specify. This can be passed as a command line argument to the dpinst.exe. You can check these flags by running the command : \dpinst.exe /?